# Check for duplicates before import

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am importing data emails from outlook into my database. I would like to check a condition before importing but am unsure how to go about it. Here is a sample of the text I am importing:

```
Transmit:  Date: 

*** R O U T I N E         *** Request No.: 123456789

Operators Notified: 


Start Date/Time:    01/01/18   At 00:15  Expiration Date: 01/01/18 

Location Information: 
County:     Municipality: 
Subdivision/Community:  
Street:               0 FAKE ST
Nearest Intersection: FAKE ST
Other Intersection:    
Lat/Lon: 
Type of Work: REPAIR  
Block:                Lot:                Depth: 2FT 

Extent of Work:  BEGINS 53FT W OF C/L OF INTERSECTION AND EXTENDS 785FT
 W.  MARK A 3FT RADIUS OF POLE NUMBERS 000/000, 000/000

Remarks:  
 Working For Contact:  NO ONE

Working For: NO ONE
Address:     123 FAKE ST
City:        SPRINGFIELD
Phone:       555-555-5555   Ext:  

Excavator Information: 
Caller:      NO ONE
Phone:       555-555-5555   Ext:  

Excavator:   NO ONE

Address:     123 FAKE ST
City:        SPRINGFIELD
Phone:       555-555-5555   Ext:          Fax:  
Cellular:     
Email:       EMAIL@EMAIL.COM

End Request
```

I would like to check the sequence number field prior to import and only import if that number does not exist.

below is the code i am using for import. any help is greatly appreciated. thank you!

```
If InStr(1, abody(j), "Request No.:", 1) Then
   reQuest = Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "Request No.:") + 13)
   Me.Requestnumber = reQuest
```

I have tried the following

```
If DCount("*", "import table", "[requestnumber] = " & Me![Requestnumber] & "") > 0 Then
      MsgBox "request number already existes."
```

but i receive an error "run-time error '3075'
syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[requestnumber]='.

any ideas?

my duplicate query

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW First([Import Table].requestnumber) AS FirstOfrequestnumber, [Import Table].RequestType, [Import Table].ID
FROM [Import Table]
GROUP BY [Import Table].RequestType, [Import Table].ID
HAVING (((First([Import Table].requestnumber)) In (SELECT [requestnumber] FROM [Import Table] As Tmp GROUP BY [requestnumber],[RequestType] HAVING Count(*)>1  And [RequestType] = [Import Table].[RequestType])))
ORDER BY First([Import Table].requestnumber), [Import Table].RequestType;
```

Possible working delete dupes

```
DELETE [Import Table].ID, ([Import Table].[requestnumber]) AS Expr1, [Import Table].requestnumber, [Import Table].[ID]
FROM [Import Table]
WHERE (((([Import Table].[requestnumber])) In (SELECT [requestnumber] FROM [Import Table] As Tmp GROUP BY [requestnumber],[RequestType] HAVING Count(*)>1  And [RequestType] = [Import Table].[RequestType])) AND (([Import Table].[ID])>(SELECT Min(ID) 
     FROM [import table] AS T 
     WHERE T.requestnumber=[import table].requestnumber)));
```

Comment: Use _DLookup_ to check if the value exists.

Comment: I have used ````If DCount("requestnumber", "import table", stLinkCriteria) > 0 Then
        'Undo duplicate entry
      MsgBox "dupe"         but I am importing multiple items and if the first one is a duplicate it just stops importing... any help?

Comment: Do the check for every value.

Answer (score 0):

You could select Distinct records, something like this.

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = Currentdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT DoID, LtID FROM YourStagingTable")
Do Until rst.EOF
  Currentdb.Execute "INSERT INTO YourLiveTable(Col1, Col2, etc) VALUES(" & rst("Col1") & "," & rst("Col2") & ", etc)
  rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

Or, if you already have dupes in your table, check fro dupes and delete them (according to whatever criteria you specify).

```
DELETE ID
FROM Table1
WHERE Items In 
    (SELECT Items 
     FROM Table1 
     GROUP BY Items 
     HAVING Count(*)>1) 
And ID >
    (SELECT Min(ID) 
     FROM Table1 AS T 
     WHERE T.Items=Table1.Items);
```

Of course, in Access, unlike SQL Server, you have a Wizard to help you find dupes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!, using your second code, can I manipulate to delete a record only if one field is the same and another is different. Example if field "RequestNumber" and "RequestType" are the same then delete the record; but if "RequestNumber" is the same but "RequstType" is different then don't delete. An example: if there are two records with data: "RequestNumber" -0001 and "RequestType" -Routine then delete one of the records.  But if there are two records, one is "RequestNumber"- 0001 & "RequestType" -Routine and the other is "RequestNumber"- 0001 & "RequestType" -Update, then keep both records?

Comment: Well, it sounds like the two records are different.  If "RequestNumber" is the same but "RequstType" is different then don't delete.  Is that what you want to achieve?  The 'And' clause looks to determine if both conditions are true and then run the delete process.  The 'Or' clause will determine if one or the other is true.   Maybe that's what you want.  Make sure you back up all your data before running delete processes on your data-sets.

Comment: correct, but i am having trouble getting the code to work. I was able to configure a check duplicate query with the criteria but not a delete using the code that i just posted in the original post, your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I just updated my original post.  Use the Wizard to find dupes.  Experiment with choosing multiple fields to get what you need.  If the logic is not exactly what you want, open the final query that the Wizard generates, and edit the SQL from there.  Change 'AND' to 'OR', if that's the ask.  That should give you what you want.  Hopefully that helps.  I haven't used Access in a very long time.  These days, I'm not as well-versed in this tool as I was 10 years ago.

Comment: I think I got it... updated original post. if you could take a look and see if you think it is doing what I explained I want it to do. I believe it is, but confirmation is always helpful lol... thanks for your help!